# How to take picture using surface view with camera and display in imageview

Tags: android

I have the requirment in one my activity imageview and button  if user click the take picture button.I have to show preview another activity from preview activity user click the button  and take the picture and display in the imageview in previous activity   I have to open front face camera for capturing user image eg if i am using tablet I have to take my picture can anybody tell how to do?  can anybody provide sample code

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can start camera and take picture using this code

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 999);

//this method will be called once user takes the pictur
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{  
    if (requestCode == 999) 
    {  
        if(data.getExtras() != null)
        {
            //here is the image from camera
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        }  
    }
}
```

That is how you can create an image view and display Bitmap in that ImageView

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: If I want open front face camera